# Xamarin, How do you call a seque, only if a if statement is true?

Tags: ios, xamarin, segue

Xamarin , How do you call a seque, only if a if statement is true ?

Comment: Are you talking about starting a new view controller, or the performing and not performing the transition (animation) of a UIStoryboardSegue via `perform` between two view controllers...?

Comment: he performing and not performing the transition (animation) of a UIStoryboardSegue via perform between two view controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform a Segue based on some condition, you have to override shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier method.

override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return true
}

First perform a check of your segue indentifier and then return true of you want your segue to be performed.